# Why can't I toggle the visibility of every element (within a group) in a for statement, only the last element in the group gets toggled?

Tags: javascript, closures, foreach

The script fires `Toggle` fine on each `Control`'s (`Controls[i]`) `Click`. If the `Control`'s first `OL` element is not `Visible` it should be set `Visible` and all other elements in `Controls` that are not the current `Control` (`Controls[i]`) should be set `Hidden`. If the `Control`'s first `OL` element is `Visible` it should be set `Hidden`.

## .js

```
function Toggle(Control){

var Controls=document.getElementsByTagName("ol",document.getElementById("Quote_App"));
var Control=Control.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0];

if(Control.style.visibility!="visible"){

    for(var i=0;i<Controls.length;i++){

/* (function(){ */

        if(Controls[i]!=Control){

            Control.style.visibility="hidden";

        }else{

            Control.style.visibility="visible";

        };

/* })(); */

    };

}else{

    Control.style.visibility="hidden";

};

};

function Event(Mode,Function,Event,Element,Capture_or_Bubble){
if(Mode.toLowerCase()!="remove"){
    if(Element.addEventListener){
        if(!Capture_or_Bubble){
            Capture_or_Bubble=false;
        }else{
            if(Capture_or_Bubble.toLowerCase()!="true"){
                Capture_or_Bubble=false;
            }else{
                Capture_or_Bubble=true;
            };
        };
        Element.addEventListener(Event,Function,Capture_or_Bubble);
    }else{
        Element.attachEvent("on"+Event,Function);
    };
};
};

function Controls(){
var Controls=document.getElementById("Quote_App").getElementsByTagName("dd");
for(var i=0;i<Controls.length;i++){
    (function(){
        var Control=Controls[i];
        Event("add",function(){

            Toggle(Control);

        },"click",Control);
    })();
};
};

Event("add",Controls,"load",window);
```

I am sure it's something with the `For` statement, in the source you can see I've commented out a closure that I tried, but that too didn't work. I'm still starting out so not very competent with closures.

Your help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're only ever setting the visibility of Control, which you are initialising as Controls[0] and never changing?

Comment: What a silly oversight on my part. I have been looking way to deep for a solution and skimmed right over the obvious!

Comment: Kudos Colin, I will be accepting your answer in 2 minutes when the Web site lets me!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change line 14 from `Control.style.visibility="hidden";` to `Controls[i].style.visibility="hidden";` and it all works wonderfully!

Kudos to Colin Fine!